# How come my UI wont update and databind when I set the DataContext to a object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

So at this point I am very confused. The way I have it bound at the moment works just perfectly, but I would like to databind using multiple classes. So what I have right now (the working version) is this.. In my MainWindow I've setup the DataContext to a new instance of my class called `Server`

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = server;
}
```

And I've bound a few properties to a couple of controls like so

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="Scroller" Margin="266,95,10,192" Background="#1f1f1f">
    <StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConsoleOutput, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                               Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"
                               Name="SavedBlocks" FontFamily="Consolas"
                               LayoutUpdated="SavedBlocks_LayoutUpdated" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And this right here being my `Server` class

```
public class Server : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string consoleInput = string.Empty;
    public ObservableCollection<Message> consoleOutput = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

    public Server()
    {

    }

    public string ConsoleInput
    {
        get => consoleInput;
        set
        {
            consoleInput = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ConsoleInput");
        }
    }


private void OKDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ServerIsRunning)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))

                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        if (e.Data.Contains("ERROR"))
                        {
                            ConsoleOutput.Add(new Message { Text = e.Data, Foreground = ERRORBrush });
                            ConsoleInput = string.Empty;
                            return;
                        }

                        if (e.Data.Contains("WARN"))
                        {
                            ConsoleOutput.Add(new Message { Text = e.Data, Foreground = WARNINGBrush });
                            ConsoleInput = string.Empty;
                            return;
                        }

                        ConsoleOutput.Add(new Message { Text = e.Data, Foreground = OKBrush });
                        ConsoleInput = string.Empty;
                    });
            }
        }


    public ObservableCollection<Message> ConsoleOutput
    {
        get => consoleOutput;
        set
        {
            consoleOutput = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ConsoleOutput");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And as you can see the ObservableCollection has the type of Message which would be this class

```
public class Message : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Message()
    {
        _foreground = Brushes.Green;
    }
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); }
    }

    private Brush _foreground;
    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return _foreground; }
        set
        {
            _foreground = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Foreground");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the issue I bumped into was when I tried creating a `MasterViewModel` class that would contain properties of all the other classes like so

```
public class MasterViewModel
{
    public Server ServerViewModel { get; } = new Server();
    public Player PlayerViewModel { get; } = new Player();
    public Message MessageViewModel { get; } = new Message();
}
```

And then I was going to set the properties as following

aswell as changing the DataContext

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MasterViewModel();
}
```

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ServerViewModel.ConsoleOutput, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageViewModel.Text}"
                       Foreground="{Binding MessageViewModel.Foreground}"
                       Name="SavedBlocks" FontFamily="Consolas"
                       LayoutUpdated="SavedBlocks_LayoutUpdated" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But then all the sudden it stopped working, It wouldnt notify the UI and the UI wouldnt update at all.
Am I missing something small here? Because I canät for the life of me find the issue here.

NEW BINDING

```
static Server server = new Server();
        static Player player = new Player();
        static Message message = new Message();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MasterViewModel()
            {
                ServerViewModel = server,
                PlayerViewModel = player,
                MessageViewModel = message,
            };
        }
```

Comment: The DataContext of an item container in an ItemsControl (and hence all elements in the DataTemplate) is automatically set to the corresponding item object, i.e. the corresponding element from the ItemsSource collection. This means that the DataContext of the TextBlock in the DataTemplate already contains a Message object. Then you bind its properties like e.g. `Text="{Binding Text}"`.

Comment: I tried reverting them again and just change the DataContext but doesnt seem to change anything

Comment: Why and where "change the DataContext"? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: No like, In my MainWindow() I set it like this `DataContext = new MasterViewModel();`

Comment: If you did that, `ItemsSource="{Binding ServerViewModel.ConsoleOutput}"` binds to the ConsoleOutput collection in the ServerViewModel property of MasterViewModel. All correct.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and I left Text & Foreground untouched so they are still in their normal shape because of the ItemSource `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"` but it's still not updating the UI

Comment: It should. You must be doing something else wrong. As a note, setting `Mode=OneWay` on the ItemsSource Binding is redundant.

Comment: I added the part to the server class which I forgot to add to the post that shows how it adds to the ObservableCollection

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at `ConsoleOutput.Add(...)` to see if it's ever reached?

Comment: Yeah I did that earlier, it reaches it but yet it doesnt notify the UI

Comment: It seems to only work if I set the DataContext to a instance of the Server class directly

Comment: You might be looking at a different Server instance than the one in the MasterViewModel's ServerViewModel property. There seems to be a `server` variable somewhere in your code. Assign that to the ServerViewModel property.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have changed bindings inside ItemTemplate. `ObservableCollection<Message> ConsoleOutput` still contains Message objects with Text and Foreground properties. Binding path `MessageViewModel.Text` is invalid for Message, revert to `{Binding Text}` and `{Binding Foreground}`

Comment: I tried reverting it and it didnt seem to make much difference

Comment: what was `server` variable? please try with `DataContext = new MasterViewModel { ServerViewModel = server; }`

Comment: The server variable would be this `static Server server = new Server();` I will try yours

Comment: Also I can't set the value since it read only so it would be redundant `public Server ServerViewModel { get; } = new Server();`

Comment: my concern was that there may be some other code which work with `server` and not with `MasterViewModel.ServerViewModel`

Comment: Hm.. Yeah I dont think so, doesnt seem like it atleast

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ServerViewModel` property of the `MasterViewModel` class to the `server` object you had before:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MasterViewModel() { ServerViewModel = server };
}
```

This means that you should add a setters to the properties of `MasterViewModel`:

```
public class MasterViewModel
{
    public Server ServerViewModel { get; set; }
    public Player PlayerViewModel { get; set; }
    public Message MessageViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure to set the `PlayerViewModel` and `Message` properties as well.

Comment: That wouldnt allow me to bind to any other class would it? Since we are setting the DataContext to the instance of that class, how come that solution worked?

Comment: I guess i could do something like this.. (I'll add it to the bottom of my question) but that just looks terrible  and it feels redundant because I am creating new instances in my main method when I have that MasteViewModel containing all of them already

Comment: MasterViewModel doesn't contain any *instances*. It is a class that defines *properties* that you need to set to some instances to initialize. If you take another look at my answer, you'll see that there is no `new` keyword in there.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what i did with a small sample

```
public class MasterVM 
    {
        public ServerVM Server { get; set; }
    }

    public class ServerVM : INotifyPropertyChanged

    {
        private string serverName;
        public string ServerName {
            get
            {
                return serverName;
            }
            set
            {
                serverName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ServerName");        
            }

        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

And here is the xaml

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Change Server NAme</Button>

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Server.ServerName}" />

    </Grid>
```

and It works like a charm.

What I can suggest you to do is have an _id field in each class and initialize to new GUID and use a tool called "Snoop" to check runtime id of those objects.